# How to store list of items temporarily?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, listbox

I am trying to store a list of items i.e. a value selected from dropdown and text from textbox temporarily and then adding them 1 by one to database using foreach loop on listbox.

code behind button add event:

```
ListBox ListBoxFeatures = new ListBox();
ListBoxFeatures.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtBoxDescription.Text, ddlFeatures.SelectedValue));
```

and then i have used a foreach loop over it to grab all stored values and store in database but it always pick 1 row, means that i store only 1 row.

```
foreach(ListItem li in ListBoxFeatures.Items)
{
      String txt= li.Text;
      Int Value= li.SelectedValue.ToInt32();

      //database logic i.e. InsertMethod
}
```

Comment: Please post your foreach as well. And you are inserting only one row, why would it pick more than that?

Comment: it picks only last inserted record

Comment: my aim is to store many rows in list and then at once submit to database upon another button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you create a new listbox in each click event. You need to move the initialization outside of the button click. Assuming that `ListBoxFeatures` already exists before the button click, you can probably remove the whole line of `ListBox ListBoxFeatures = new ListBox();` from your click method.

Comment: Hang on. `ListItem` does not have a `SelectedValue`. Can you double check the code you posted? Also, when you click, do you see the items appear in the listbox properly? Forget about the database for the moment, and confirm that items are being added to the list correctly. If they don't appear, I suspect you've got the same initial problem somewhere: check where you're creating the listbox, and make sure it's somewhere that will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
foreach(ListItem li in ListBoxFeatures.Items)
{ ... }
```

**UPDATE**

Also, the button event always creates a new listbox and then inserts 1 value to it... Why would you have more than one value?

Comment: yes it was a typo, check updated question. But still same issue

Comment: yes true but i can't figure out any way to store multiple items

Comment: Just reference the listbox by the name that you gave it in the aspx section

Comment: it's not in aspx section in .cs

Comment: I don't understand, Is it a ASP.NET project or a WPF? Where is the ListBox controller initialized? Is it initialized in the View or dynamically in the Controller (Code-Behind)?

Comment: Code behind. it's asp.net

Comment: Well, if you would like the ListBox to be usable, you need to add it to a container that is defined in the asp.net .aspx page (not the code-behind)

Comment: ok worked thanks a lot but i am confused that why it works this way ? it hsould have worked because it was defined

Comment: You must attach it to the View for the user to be able to change it... If you create it independently and add items to it, it will just be a collection, like List<object>().